# jQuery on Firefox

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery.  I am studying Javascript and jQuery and when I open the jQuery programs from the course (not my own programs but the course programs) I get an error in that it says that $ is not defined starting at the ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Any ideas?  I am new to jQuery so I need babysteps.

Comment: What _course_?  Be very specific about what you're talking about.

Comment: Hiya have you included the Jquery src in your project something like this `<script src="/folder_name/Jquery.1.7.1.js />` have a nice one, cheerios

Comment: It is the Missing Manual course on Javascript and jquery.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I included the code, yes the function is closed and the jquery file is included.  Thank you all.

Comment: Please improve your question by **editing** it.  As it stands, I'm voting to close it.

Answer (score 3):

1. declare your jquery api
2. Your declaration must be BEFORE your function
3. If you are using other library (like mootools) it may occurs conflicts
4. This error usually means that you are not calling the pluging/jquery in the right way Use a local save file (get it from [here](http://jquery.com/)) or use an external link

   - [External libraries on google](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide)
   - https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js for a jquery external link

You can also follow this example:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // content
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, these are programs that came with my course book so I am surprised that there are issues.

Comment: @user1364902 No problem, if you need some help with something else let us know. PS (if you're missing something in this question too), besides you can pick a correct answer if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. You have commented the close tag.

Your code

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#animate').click(function() {
    $(this).animate( { width: '400px', height: '400px' }, 1000, 'easeInBounce'); // end animate }); // end click }); // end ready 
</script>
```

Replace with this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#animate').click(function() {
    $(this).animate( { width: '400px', height: '400px' }, 1000, 'easeInBounce'); // end animate }); // end click }); // end ready 
    });
});</script>
```

Comment: <html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Easing Example I</title>
<link href="../_css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
#animate {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: white;
 padding: 20px;
}
#animate p {
 color: black; 
}
</style>
<script src="../_js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../_js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#animate').click(function() {
   $(this).animate(
   {
    width: '400px',
    height: '400px'
   }, 1000,
   'easeInBounce'); // end animate
  }); // end click
}); // end ready
</script>
</head>

Comment: @user1364902, please include your code by **editing your original question**.  What you did is unfair to everyone else trying to answer your question.

Comment: The code has been included.  when I tried to include it I ran out of characters.

Comment: @user1364902,  clearly you're confused as you have **not** included your code **within** your **original question** as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the jQuery reference with the correct version? Like shown below

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```